# HTTP Methods at the command line

Tags: command-line, networking

I am wanting to make use of a web API from the command line.

My understanding is that HTTP Methods are as follows.

```
GET
POST
PUT
HEAD
PATCH
OPTIONS
```

When I enter these individually in Konsole it displays usage info for `GET`, `POST`, and `HEAD` but not for any of the others.

Why aren't all the methods available?

Answer (score 2):

The `GET`, `HEAD` and `POST` commands on your system are likely symbolic links to `/usr/bin/lwp-request`, and are provided as part of [LWP - The World-Wide Web library for Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) (installable on Ubuntu as the **libwww-perl** package):

```
$ dpkg -L libwww-perl | grep '/bin/'
/usr/bin/lwp-download
/usr/bin/lwp-dump
/usr/bin/lwp-mirror
/usr/bin/lwp-request
/usr/bin/GET
/usr/bin/HEAD
/usr/bin/POST
```

The simple answer to your question is that `lwp-request` does not currently implement the other methods.